# Как изменить css файл в потоке Gulp, но при этом не испортить sourcemaps?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Здравствуйте! Есть необходиость изменить css код в потоке (добавить к url изображений ?хэш), но при этом не испортить карты исходных кодов, присутствующие в файле. В данный момент удается обработать css файл, но карта нарушается (названия файлов не сохраняются, адресация портится). Я так понимаю мне для этого нужен плагин [vinyl-sourcemaps-apply](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-sourcemaps-apply) и [rework](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework) + rework-url

```
gulp.src('./source/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(antiCache(fileHashes))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
```

где fileHashes представляет из себя объект с содержимым вида`"path/to/image.png":"a9ecbba8ef"`. Функция antiCache не должна ничего испортить, только изменить урлы:

```
function antiCache(fileHashes) {
return through.obj(function (file, encoding, callback) {
    var content = file.contents.toString(),
        options = {};

    if (file.sourceMap) {
        options.outSourceMap = file.relative;
    }

    var mangled = (function() {
        var m = rework(file.contents.toString()).use(reworkUrl(function (url) {
            if (fileHashes.hasOwnProperty(path.basename(url))) {
                return url + '?' + fileHashes[path.basename(url)];
            }
            return url;
        }));
        m = css.stringify(m.obj, { sourcemap: true });
        m.code = new Buffer(m.code.replace(/\n\/\/# sourceMappingURL=.+?$/, ''));
        return m;
    })();

    file.contents = mangled.code;
    if (file.sourceMap) {
        var map = mangled.map;
        map.file = path.relative(file.base, file.path);
        applySourceMap(file, map);
    }
    this.push(file);
    callback(null, file);
});
}
```

Как в этой функции не испортить карты исходных кодов, мне всего лишь нужно заменить ссылки картинок и все.

Answer (score 1):

Можно разделить это на два таска: действия над файлами и действия над измененными файлами.

Первый будет выглядеть примерно так (файлы копируются во временную папку):

```
gulp.task('css-make-tmp', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/**/!(_)*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(postcss([
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['> 0.01%']
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulpif(IS_PRODUCTION, minifyCss({advanced: false})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/css'));
});
```

Второй, что то вроде:

```
gulp.task('css-build', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./tmp/manifest/*.json', './tmp/css/**/*.css'])
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest('css.json'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/manifest'));
});
```

Ну и объединяющий таск:

```
gulp.task('css', function (callback) {
    del(['./tmp/css', './build/**/*.css'], function () {
        runSequence('css-make-tmp', 'css-build', callback);
    });
});
```

**P.S.** пример с моего проекта.